# Product page meta titles - appearance in search results

Tags: magento-1.9, product, html, meta-tags, meta-title

Hej.
I'm working on a site with Magento 1.9.2.1 CE, https://www.elcykelsalg.dk/.
In search results, the products are displayed with an attribute (Elcykler) after the meta title separated with a "-", which I have been unable to change or remove.
I have tried to change the standard title under System->Configuration->Design
->HTML Head, but it has still not changed in Google search results.
I have also been looking at the category tree, where both "Elcykler" and "Cykler" are sub categories of the default category, but the only possible explanation, that I can come up with, would be that one comes before the other, or that I have not been setting any of them to be Anchor.
What can I do, or what do I do wrong ?

P.S.
"Elcykler" means e-bikes, and the shop does sell e-bikes, but also normal bikes "Cykler", which makes it somehow misleading, that the first one appears with all products from other categories in search results[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after I posted this, so if anybody else should experience a similar problem, I will leave a possible solution.
It seems that in this case, enabling flat categories and products solved it

System > configuration > catalog > frontend section

so it will be worth giving it a try.